# how to display and set user rights in firebird database

Tags: sql, firebird, rights

I tried but all time all failed about displaying and setting user rights in firebird databases. I used ;

GSEC> display

but it just display users name. I want to see all rights and I want  to set them. Can we do such this option and management ?

Regards,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Firebird `gsec` utility only manages users and their passwords in the global security database (`security2.fdb` in Firebird 2.0 and higher). The rights of a user are managed per database (except for the user `SYSDBA`) and cannot be managed with `gsec`.

Per database user rights are controlled by defining roles (optionally), assigning rights to roles and/or users, and assigning roles to users in a specific database. Rights assigned to a role are only applied when the role is specified on attach, otherwise only the user rights apply.

Assigning rights is done with `GRANT` and `REVOKE`. For details, check the [Firebird 2.5 Language Reference chapter Security](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-security) and changes for Firebird 3 documented in the [Firebird 3 release notes](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-security.html), and/or the [Interbase 6.0 Operations Guide](https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/reference-manuals/), chapter 5 Database Security, Interbase 6.0 Language Reference and Interbase 6.0 Data Definition Guide (both downloadable from the same location as the operations guide) and changes documented in the [Firebird Language Reference Update](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25.html).

To display the current rights granted in a database, you can use the `isql` tool, command [`show grants`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/isql/firebird-isql.html#isql-show-grants). You will need to connect to the specific database you want the information for. For other tools or normal client connections you will need to query the system tables (specifically `RDB$USER_PRIVILEGES`) yourself, or use the features of the tool (eg Flamerobin can display the rights as well).

If no rights are granted (which means only `SYSDBA` and the database owner have rights), the `show grants;` will output:

```
SQL> show grants;
There is no privilege granted in this database
```

For example assume I have table `ITEMS` and I grant `SELECT` rights to a role `TESTROLE`, the output will be:

```
SQL> CREATE ROLE TestRole;
SQL> GRANT SELECT ON ITEMS TO TestRole;
SQL> SHOW GRANTS;

/* Grant permissions for this database */
GRANT SELECT ON ITEMS TO ROLE TESTROLE
```

Now if I also assign additional `UPDATE` rights:

```
SQL> GRANT UPDATE ON ITEMS TO TestRole;
SQL> SHOW GRANTS;

/* Grant permissions for this database */
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON ITEMS TO ROLE TESTROLE
SQL>
```

If instead you query the system table `RDB$USER_PRIVILEGES` you'll see the list below (+ more rights for the DB owner):

```
USER      GRANTOR  PRIVILEGE GRANT_OPTION RELATION_NAME FIELD_NAME USER_TYPE OBJECT_TYPE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TESTROLE  SYSDBA   S         0            ITEMS         [null]     13        0
TESTROLE  SYSDBA   U         0            ITEMS         [null]     13        0
```

(left out the `RDB$` prefix from the column names for brevity)

- `RDB$USER` is the name of the object that received the rights. Here it is `TESTROLE` which is a role (indicated by column `RDB$USER_TYPE` value 13).
- `RDB$GRANTOR` is the user that granted the right.
- `RDB$PRIVILEGE` is the right granted

  - `S`: `SELECT`
  - `U`: `UPDATE`
  - `D`: `DELETE`
  - `I`: `INSERT`
  - `R`: `REFERENCE` (for creating foreign keys referencing the specified table (or specific column))
  - `X`: `EXECUTE` (for stored procedures, maybe also UDFs)
- `RDB$GRANT_OPTION`: `1`: User can grant right to another user, `0` (sometimes `NULL`), user cannot grant this right
- `RDB$RELATION_NAME`: Name of the table (or other database object)
- `RDB$FIELD_NAME` : Name of column in a table (`NULL` means right is granted for all columns)
- `RDB$USER_TYPE` : Object type of the `RDB$USER` column (`13` is a role, `8` a normal user, other object types are possible as well, eg granting rights to a stored procedure)
- `RDB$OBJECT_TYPE`: Object type of the `RDB$RELATION_NAME` (eg 0: Relation, a normal table).

A full list of object types can be obtained from `RDB$TYPES` (this doesn't mean rights can be granted on or to all object types). Check the documentation for details.

Comment: Thank you Mark i was already tried what you said. But nothing usefull .. :(

Comment: Be more specific 'nothing useful' doesn't really help me to find what information you are missing,

Comment: @MusaGezer I have included an example on how you can use `show grants` or the `RDB$USER_PRIVILEGES` system table.

Comment: Hello Mark, sorry for couldnt responde you. Thanks for information.. However i need to see rights not assign right. I want to check which user has which right.

Comment: @MusaGezer My answer includes how you can lookup assigned rights. I also show assignment to illustrate how they are shown in Firebird ISQL and the `RDB$USER_PRIVILEGES` table.

Answer (score 2):

The `gsec` utility allows one to manage users which are allowed to connect to specific Firebird server instance. Ie it allows to manage the user list Firebird server would recognize (see [gsec manual](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/gsec.html)). But it doesn't allow you to manage what each user is allowed to do in some particular database. For managing user rights in particular database you should use roles and `GRANT` and `REVOKE` statements.

I suggest you use some GUI tool to manage user rights, ie [Flamerobin](http://flamerobin.org/).

Comment: I also search GRANT and REVOKE but i couldnt find what i am looking for

Comment: If you mean you didn't find the syntax of these commands then see Mark's answer, he postet the link to the IB manual where these are documented.