# Firebird DDL for user and privileges

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5, ibexpert

I have Firebird 2.5 and I need to extract all user and privileges as DDL to export to another Firebird database.

For example, I need get the script for user max

```
"Create user max  FIRSTNAME 'Max' LASTNAME 'Power' Grant admin option";
```

I use IB Expert, but did not find this option to extract the DDL.

Comment: Users themselves are not maintained in the database, they are part of the security database of the Firebird server installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools -> Grants/Rights Manager -> Toolbar -> Save -> To Script Executive

[image: IB Expert]

Alternatively, go to the Tools -> Extract Metadata -> Settings and down there check the "extract grants" checkbox.

---

You also have to remember that users themselves do not exist in the database (only grants do), users they exist in the server, not the database.

See [how to display and set user rights in firebird database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656406)

Also see GSEC documentation:

- http://www.destructor.de/firebird/gsec.htm
- https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/gsec/firebird-gsec.html#gsec-batch

`gsec -user sysdba -password <password> -database <databasename> -display` - a command like that should display all the users registered with the server used to connect to the database. It would be trivial to take the user list and add the `create user`  command to every one.

---

There is one more niche case that Firebird might have no any users, borrowing them from the host operating system. It is called "Trusted Authentication" mode. If GSEC would show no users or too few ones - check authentication settings in the relevant `firebird.conf`, maybe you would have to dump users list from Windows, not from Firebird.

- https://www.firebirdsql.org/rlsnotesh/rnfb210-wintrusted.html
- https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/blob/master/doc/README.trusted_authentication

Comment: Thank you very instructive reply.  As a alternative I found the tool Firebird Maestro, then I can extraxt all SQL for create user and grant permission.